# Measure of distance between a word and set of words

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining

I am working on the following problem:

Given a list of words $W$ and non-words $NW$, I would like to have a classifier telling me whether a new word $w$ is a Word or not (i.e. $W(w)$ or NonWord $NW(w)$). I calculate 2,3,4 grams for all words in $W$ and $NW$. As a feature, I want to calculate the distance for each word (in the training and test sets) to $W$. Can you advice on a measure of distance?

Comment: Maybe you can research work conducted in error detection and correction where the focus is to spot "non-words"

Comment: What are the characteristics of words and non-words? The answer highly depends on what your data is, just describing it as "words" is not enough.

Comment: Words are generated from a list of known strings (a dictionary of sorts) by combining known strings. Nonwords are generated in a "pseudo-random", but still learnable way.